# How to run two web service with differenct platform in same machine?

Tags: java, php, debian, squid

I want to do something like this,  I have a single machine x.x.x.x, in which i need to run two website **www.xyz.com** which is in php (run in apache 2 server) and another javaEE service in **www.xyz.com/service** (run in apache tomcat or glassfish server). Both need to run on port 80 (from client side view). Can you please ans me, how to do that? My machine is Debian linux 6.0.

Comment: You may handle both using one web server say `apache` running on port 80 and proxy the request `www.xyz.com/service` to other server running on some other port.

Comment: i have only one server. i need to run both on same server.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `mod_proxy` apache module which also supports AJP protocol, when loading additional module `mod_proxy_ajp`.

Simple sample:

```
<Location /service/>
   ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009/service/
</Location>
```

where 8009 is the port defined for the connector in tomcat `server.xml`, and /service is the context root (which may also be different from "/service").

Documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html